# Replace php file include after form action with next include

Tags: file, post, include

How can i include a php file after form action POST? All of the file must be loaded on the same page.

What i have:

```
if ($_POST['vaste_kosten'] > 0) echo "<form method='post'action='mail.php'>
```

I don't like the iframe function in HTML to do this.

Answer (score 0):

> How can i include a php file after
>   form action POST

you can use [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php), [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php), [require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) , [require_once](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require-once.php) whichever you prefer

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
   include('file.php');
   include('anotherfile.php');
}
```

Comment: This works too, but the code don't check of the value higher is then 0.

Comment: The check works now, but i dont understand how i can replace te first include.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you mean, but it certainly answers what you're asking. You should simply use the [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) function, as follows:

```
if ($_POST['vaste_kosten'] > 0) {
    echo "<form method='post'action='mail.php'>";
    include("path_to_file/file.php");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks this works but can i replace the first form? Now come the next form below the first form.

Comment: @user636613 Sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean. You could certainly put the form line inside the included file if that helps. I'd recommend reading the PHP documentation I've linked above - it should make it clear what's happening.

Comment: There is one form, after clicking on the sumbit button must loaded the include file on the form (replace).

I hope you understand it.